# Cakephp open sourse applications to download

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0

I am a cakephp beginner.. to boost learning curve i am looking for open source application which can be downloaded from web.. please suggest me web adressess where i can find the same..

Comment: here's a quick search of some OS cake projects: https://github.com/search?q=cakephp&type=Everything&repo=&langOverride=&start_value=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Believe me. Looking at open source is not the best way to start learning. I made that mistake when I started learning CAKEPHP. What you should do is look at books, tutorials, and actually practice with your own code before looking into open source.

any open source is usually code that is written by masters. as a beginner you will get lost and it will you keep you from learning CAKE.

for me the best way is actually THE CAKEPHP MANUAL.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Look at http://croogo.org/ it's an open source cms based on cakephp.

But i would suggest you to do the cakephp blog tutorial: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples.html

this will help you much more.

Answer (score 0):

For that You have to understand :--

MVC :-- 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller

Then 
Get there and do the blog tutorial >> http://book.cakephp.org/view/219/Blog
Read that >> http://book.cakephp.org/view/10/Understanding-Model-View-Controller

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/index.html

For some video tutorial:-

http://tv.cakephp.org/video/andrewperk/2011/01/26/cakephp_blog_tutorial_part_9_-_layouts